# AS3: method/function in class only called on one class instance?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I'm quite a noob to programming, so please bear with me.

I have a Neighbour class. In another class, I instantiate 3 separate instances of the Neighbour class, stored into an array (collisionArray_Neighbour). There is a function (randomisePosition) in Neighbour class.

The problem is: the randomisePosition() function is only called by one Neighbour instance. Even though I iterate through the instances with an array, to call the Neighbour update() function on each. This update function calls the randomisePosition() function.

It may be due to the arrays, as if I remove an the one instance calling randomisePosition() from the array, by colliding with an instance in-game, another instance, but still only one out of the array, calls the function randomisePosition.

This is the code that adds the instances to an array:

```
public function populateNeighbourCollisionArray()
{
    for (var iN:int = 0; iN < enemyMaxAmount; iN++)
    {
        if (collisionArray_Neighbour.length < 3)
        {
            collisionArray_Neighbour.push(new Neighbour(this));
            level01.addChild(collisionArray_Neighbour[collisionArray_Neighbour.length - 1]);        
        }
    }
}
```

This calls the update function for each instance:

```
for (var i = 0; i < collisionArray_Neighbour.length; i++)
{
    collisionArray_Neighbour[i].update();
}
```

The update function in Neighbour class:

```
public function update()
{
    if (animationComplete)
    {
        trace("randomise position...");
        randomisePosition();
        gotoAndPlay("startFading");
        //startTimer();
    }
}
```

randomisePosition function that seems to be only called on one Neighbour instance:

```
private function randomisePosition()
{
    trace("position randomised");
    var randomX = Math.ceil(randomRange(0, 100));
    var randomY = Math.ceil(randomRange(50, 400));
    this.x = parentClassRef.player.x + randomX;
    this.y = randomY;               
}
```

Comment: This is normal behaviour. To understand take this example:  have 3 instances of Neighnour:  Bob, John and Tom. and a new method inside increaseWeight(byValue:int);  Why calling Bob.increaseWeight(5) should affect the other 2.  In order to call this method to all of your neighbours, store them in an array and when you need it just loop into the array and call randomize for each one of them.

Comment: @Adrian Pirvulescu In my code I already in my code, call the update() function for Neighbour for each Neighbour instance via an array, like you said. And through this update() function randomisePosition/increaseWeight is called. Is this not the same thing?

Comment: sorry but in your sample code I do not see where you dot that !?

Comment: touche lol. But now that you know about it, do you have any idea why the function is only called on one instance?

Comment: a) presuming you have 3 instances: is it called 3 times on same instance or just once one 1 instance ?  b) please post the complete code, maybe somewhere there is a mistake ?

Comment: I would presume each instance would call it's own update(), and therefore its own randomisePosition(), function?

Comment: Looks ok for me, i see no reasons why this should not work the way you want